# Name of a sci-fi film from the 1980s that opens with an astronaut being killed by an alien that takes the form of a beautiful woman?

Tags: story-identification, space

Another one of my long-shot questions, I fear.   I only saw part of the film, but hopefully the scene I remember will be memorable enough someone will recall it and the film's title.

**Plot Details/Summary**

The film opens with an astronaut exploring the surface of a moon.  I believe it is one of the moons of either Jupiter or Saturn.  The moon has an atmosphere of some sort, and I recall rocky formations and I think a blue-ish sandy/icy soil.  The astronaut is in his space suit.  Both the planet and the spacesuit look fairly well done, from an F/X point of few.

At one point, the astronaut sees a stunning blonde woman walking the surface of this moon.  I remember her looking very 80's New Wave-ish - bleached hair, heavy makeup, I'm thinking some sort of 80's club clothes outfit?  The woman in question might be an ex-girlfriend of the astronaut's (it sticks in my mind he may have recognized her), or it may not have.

I'm not sure how long the encounter lasts, or if the "woman" is chased by the astronaut. I do recall the woman rips open the astronaut's suit or helmet, and he dies.  The woman, who is apparently some sort of alien, gives the astronaut a curious look and I believe she kisses him before bolting off to wherever.

**Timeframe/Details**

I caught this one on Showtime, somewhere between the mid-1980s to very early 90s.  I don't think it was an old film at the time.  The effects looked contemporary, as did the appearance of the alien/woman.  It was in color, and most likely an R-rated film.  I don't recall either of the two actors, which may indicate this was a fairly low-budget flick, despite the decent special effects.

Comment: Reminds me of https://pbfcomics.com/comics/zarflax/ (Warning: may be not safe for work, if someone is looking closely over your shoulder, and depending on your workplace. Be warned that if you browse around there, some PBF strips are yet more NSFW. Oddly, this particular strip no longer seems to be listed in the strip index, so it took Googling to re-find it.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This could be [Creature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creature_(1985_film)) a 1985 American Sci-Fi Horror film.

The film is set on Titan, the largest of Saturn's moons.

> In the film's prologue, two geological researchers for the American multinational corporation NTI encounter an ancient alien laboratory on Titan, the largest moon of Saturn. In the lab is an egg-like container which is keeping an alien creature alive. The creature emerges and kills the researchers. Two months later, the geologists' spaceship crashes into the space station Concorde in orbit around Earth's moon, its pilot having died in his seat.
>
> NTI dispatches a new ship, the Shenandoah, to Titan. Its crew, consisting of Captain Mike Davison (Stan Ivar), Susan Delambre (Marie Laurin), Jon Fennel (Robert Jaffe), Dr. Wendy H. Oliver (Annette McCarthy), David Perkins (Lyman Ward) and Beth Sladen (Wendy Schaal), is accompanied by the taciturn security officer Melanie Bryce (Diane Salinger). While in orbit, the crew locate a signal coming from the moon—the distress call of a ship from the rival German multinational Richter Dynamics. Their own landing turns disastrous when the ground collapses beneath their landing site, dropping the ship into a cavern and wrecking it. When radio communication fails, a search party is sent out to contact the Germans.

Potentially the scene that the OP remembers is when one of the male members of the crew sees one of the female members walking around outside the spaceship.  The female crew member was supposed to be dead following an earlier encounter with the aliens.

> Unsupervised in the medbay, Fennel sees the undead Delambre through a porthole and follows her outside. She strips naked, and he stands transfixed while she removes his helmet. He asphyxiates, and then she attaches an alien parasite to his head.

It features early special effects work by Robert and Dennis Skotak, who would go on to design the special effects for Aliens, which would explain the decent special effects remembered.

The film is on YouTube

Comment: Unquestionably, this is the film I was trying to remember.  All the details fit.